# Escape double quatation on pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, double-quotes

When I read a CSV file including double quatations, `CParserError` occurrs. How do I avoid this error and load the CSV file correctly?

Please assume that I can not edit a CSV file because actually there are a lot of similar files to load.

my.csv

```
abc,",def
```

csv_loader.py

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("my.csv")
```

Error message

> CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at line 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is setting the `quotechar` to the same as the delimiter, see [github issue 5500](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/5500#issuecomment-28533772):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""a,b,c
abc,",def
"""
#after testing replace StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), quotechar=',')
print (df)

     a  b    c
0  abc  "  def
```